# Prevent content script injection when private browsing activated?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a content script that I'd like to prevent from injecting itself when private browsing is enabled. I'm using the latest version of the Firefox add-on SDK (1.9).

I'm injecting content like this:

```
// lib/main.js
var pb = require('private-browsing');

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://*",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('jquery.min.js'),
                      self.data.url('content.js')],
  contentSriptWhen: 'start',
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    // do some stuff
  }
});
```

Wrapping the whole thing is an if statement doesn't work because the pageMode attachment is not evaluated for each injection. Entering and leaving private browsing doesn't trigger a reevaluation either.

```
if (!pb.isActive) {
  // the code I have above.
}
```

I could listen to the `pb.on('start')` event but I don't think there's a way to unattach pagemods. I could probably no-op the content script if private browsing mode is enabled but that seems like a hack which could lead to security concerns down the road.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `destroy` method:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/page-mod.html#destroy%28%29

It's important to note that if you made some changes to the existing pages you have to manually remove them.

So, you could have something like:

```
const pb = require('private-browsing');
const { PageMod } = require('page-mod');

var mod = null;

var options = {
  include: "http://*",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('jquery.min.js'),
                      self.data.url('content.js')],
  contentSriptWhen: 'start',
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    // do some stuff
  }
}

if (!pb.isActive)
  mod = PageMod(options);

pb.on("start", function(){
  if (mod) {
    mod.destroy();
    mod = null;
  }
})

pb.on("stop", function() {
  if (!mod) {
    mod = PageMod(options);
  }
})
```

Didn't test, but just to give to you a rough idea.
I'm not sure that create/destroy the PageMod every time is a good thing.

***Note** original post on mozilla-labs-jetpack mailing list, copied the answer here to be useful to someone else that doesn't know the ML.*

Comment: I'm using `contentStyle` and `contentStyleFile` to inject css, when i call the destroy method it restore the original css on the webpage immediately, but when i call `PageMod(options)` nothing happens untill i reload the page!!! is there a way i can make the content script start without having to reload the page?

Comment: @razzak, you probably need the [attachTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29) with a value like `['existing', 'top']` or similar.

Comment: yep i figured it out few days ago, `existing` was the magic word.